# Trying to configure CMake tool chain on Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ninja, cmake-gui

The software will eventually run on an embedded Linux platform. To start, we wrote a library, with all C files in the same folder, and C++ files in a test folder under it.

> - MyLib
>
>   - a.c
>   - b.c
> - MyLib/test
>
>   - test.cpp

This works on Windows 10, using **CMake**, **Ninja** and **CLang** plus **doctest** as a test framework. All of these tools are installed under **vcpkg**.

I am now trying to get everything configured and running on Ubuntu 16.04. All of the tools and source code have been retrieved from our repository. I have tried to build the library and test with Qt, cmake-gui and the command line without success.

Using CMake-gui, after browsing to the source and destination, clicking the Configure button causes the error

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".
>   CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM was not set.

The **ninja** program is in ~/../vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja-1.8.2-linux/ folder.

I had different errors when trying to build from the command line.

Are there any examples of configurations that work with controlled tools instead of those in the environment?

> > Edit: added

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

project(PSOC_LIB)

option(BUILD_TESTS "bulid tests project" OFF)

set(psoc_lib_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(psoc_lib_VERSION_MINOR 1)
set(psoc_lib_VERSION_PATCH 0)
set(psoc_lib_VERSION "${psoc_lib_VERSION_MAJOR}.${psoc_lib_VERSION_MINOR}.${psoc_lib_VERSION_PATCH}")

set(PROJ_NAME "\"PSOC Library\"") # PROJECT_NAME is a predefined variable
set(PROJECT_DESCRIPTION "\"Crossplatform library for products\"")

configure_file(include/psoc/config.h.in
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/psoc/config.h
)

set(SOURCES
# 5 *.c files
    )

add_library(PSOC_LIB ${SOURCES})


target_include_directories(PSOC_LIB PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_compile_definitions(PSOC_LIB PRIVATE _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1)

if (BUILD_TESTS)
    include(CTest)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif (BUILD_TESTS)
```

**test/CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(TEST_SOURCES
    test.cpp
)

find_package(doctest CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_runner test_runner.cpp ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_compile_definitions(test_runner PRIVATE _SILENCE_CXX17_ALLOCATOR_VOID_DEPRECATION_WARNING) #silence warnings about allocator<void> deprecation
target_compile_definitions(test_runner PRIVATE _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601) #target windows 7
target_link_libraries(test_runner PSOC_LIB doctest::doctest)

add_test(all_tests test_runner)
```

Under Windows, the files in the `test` folder are build even when `BUILD_TESTS` is OFF. Under Linux, the `test` and `Testing` folders are created only when `BUILD_TESTS` is ON.

Comment: Do you have `ninja` executable in your PATH? This is what error message talking about.

Comment: No. I ran `ninja` and it said to use `sudo apt install ninja` or `ninja-build`. I chose `ninja`. It looks like the executable is `/usr/sbin/ninja`. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean `/usr/bin/ninja` instead? Subdirectory `sbin/` is for **administration** utilities (which usually requires corresponded privileges), but `ninja` is not a tool of such kind.

Comment: No. `usr/sbin/ninja` is a 22.9 kB Program. Related text files show it to be a daemon. I did not find any new files in `usr/bin`.

Comment: So you need to have ninja **build tool** installed, and make sure that a directory with `ninja` executable is in `PATH` variable.

Comment: I have `ninja` installed. `--version` show `1.5.1`. I have three versions of `cmake`: 3.5, 3.14 and 3.15.3. Running `cmake` from my project folder only builds the library for that folder. Files in the `test` folder are ignored.

Comment: "Files in the test folder are ignored." - It is `CMakeLists.txt` script which determine which files and directories are built with the project. We cannot help you without viewing that script. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell script that builds an executable test file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Build a debug version of the PSOC_LIB and related tests
mkdir build
cd build
../../../vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.14.0-linux/cmake-3.14.0-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S ../
ninja
```